# how can I show full breadcrumbs category path on product page in Magento 2.3?

Tags: magento2.3, product-page, breadcrumbs

[image]

How can I show the full breadcrumbs category path on the product page in Magento 2.3?

i want this path complete on product detail page in breadcrumbs
[image]

Comment: can you please elaborate what you actually want to do in detail?

Comment: i hava add a picture please check

Comment: in first picture it shows me only 2 breadcrumbs path on detail page but in second picture it show me full path in breadcrumbs that i need on detail page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento by default provides this functionality in M2.3.3 or greater version. When you navigate to any product using navigation(using category) it will by default show full breadcrumbs on product page(except it will not show full breadcrumbs if you directly navigate to product using url).

Please check on this [demo](https://magento.nublue.co.uk/).

You may need to use a extension to show full breadcrumbs on product page for earlier versions.

Comment: At least in Magento 2.4.3 its not as it should be.

Answer (score 1):

Please check with below url, its module from Eadesign which have Full path categories product breadcrumb

https://github.com/EaDesgin/magento2-full-path-category-product-breadcrumb

Comment: is this madule working fine for 2.3.2? i am getting error when i go to stroes->configuration.https://prnt.sc/sst6gt

Answer (score 1):

> **Try This**

**app/code/VedoreName/ModuleName/view/frontend/layout**

**catalog_product_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="breadcrumbs" template="Magento_Theme::html/breadcrumbs.phtml" />
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Breadcrumbs" />
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Msquare post. Let's say we have a configuration setting "feature/catalog_product/add_categories_to_pdp_breadcrumbs" which enables or disables category breadcrumbs at a PDP. Then we can switch between Magento default and a custom Breadcrumb. Use a following XML code:

```
<referenceBlock name="breadcrumbs">
    <action method="setTemplate" ifconfig="feature/catalog_product/add_categories_to_pdp_breadcrumbs">
        <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Theme::html/breadcrumbs.phtml</argument>
        </action>
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Breadcrumbs"
                   ifconfig="feature/catalog_product/add_categories_to_pdp_breadcrumbs"/>
</referenceBlock>
```